# TF lite model performs worse when using Androids NNAPI

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm benchmarking various tensorflow-lite models using TFLite Model Benchmark Tool[1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/tools/benchmark), on an Xiaomi MI9. I've noticed that many models perform worse when I enable inference on Androids Neural Network API.

What could be the reasons that the model performs worse using the NNAPI?

My guess is that models that are too large can't be properly executed on the phones co-processor, and have to send data back and forth to the CPU.

Comment: Let the link to related discussion be saved here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28283

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason are in the thread suggested by Alex, particularly if you're observing this for well tested standard models like Mobilenet.